# Does an FME fmw file include the processed data in it?

Tags: fme-form, privacy

If I share an FMW file does it include the actual data or is it just the steps in the model and links to the data sources but not actual data.

Some models have links to Microsoft SQL Server databases, etc (without passwords)

I want to make sure private data is not shared when getting advise on updating a model or making it available under c3 for others to use.

Looking at the FMW in a text editor it doesn't seem to include any data - so it should be fine but just want to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FME .fmw does not include the actual data.
However, the transformers will expose the metadata, like attribute names and perhaps some values, if you have put in filters and rules. Also, as you have mentioned, you should be wary of the links to data sources.

Comment: Correct.  If you use "named connections" for your various services/databases, then those are further hidden as they are stored locally and not shipped with the workspace .fmw

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, it doesn't include the data. I know you don't want to here, but if you *did* want to include the data, then you can use File > Save as Template.

When you save a template you get a .fmwt file. That can include the data, plus database connections, web connections, and even feature caches if you want.